# How can I override tasks ``run`` and ``runMain`` in SBT to use my own ``ForkOptions``?

Tags: scala, sbt, multi-module

### Problem

In a multimodule build, each module has it's own `baseDirectory` but I would like to launch applications defined in modules employing the `baseDirectory` of the root project instead of the `baseDirectory` relative to modules involved.

This way, applications always would take relative file names from the root folder, which is a very common pattern.

The problem is that `ForkOptions` enforces the `baseDirectory` from the module and apparently there's no easy way to change that because `forkOptions` is private. I would like to pass a `forkOptions` populated with the `baseDirectory` from the root project instead.

Besides, there are modules which contain two or more applications. So, I'd like to have separate configurations for each application in a given module which contains two or more applications.

An example tells more than 1000 words:

### build.sbt

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._

lazy val buildSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Defaults.defaultSettings
lazy val forkRunOptions: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(fork := true)

addCommandAlias("r1",       "ModuleA/RunnerR1:run")
addCommandAlias("r2",       "ModuleA/RunnerR2:run")

lazy val RunnerR1 = sbt.config("RunnerR1").extend(Compile)
lazy val RunnerR2 = sbt.config("RunnerR2").extend(Compile)

lazy val root =
  project
    .in(file("."))
    .settings(buildSettings:_*)
    .aggregate(ModuleA)

lazy val ModuleA =
  project
    .in(file("ModuleA"))
    .settings(buildSettings:_*)
    .configs(RunnerR1,RunnerR2)
    .settings(inConfig(RunnerR1)(
      forkRunOptions ++
        Seq(
          mainClass in Compile :=  Option("sbt.tests.issueX.Application1"))):_*)
    .settings(inConfig(RunnerR2)(
      forkRunOptions ++
        Seq(
          mainClass in Compile :=  Option("sbt.tests.issueX.Application2"))):_*)
```

In SBT console, I would expect this:

```
> r1
This is Application1
> r2
This is Application2
```

But I see this:

```
> r1
This is Application2
> r2
This is Application2
```

What is the catch?

Not only that... SBT is running applications in process. It's not forking them. Why `fork := true` is not taking any effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

see: https://github.com/frgomes/sbt-issue-2247

Turns out that configurations do not work the way one might think they work.

The problem is that, in the snippet below, configuration `RunnerR1` does not inherit tasks from module `ModuleA` as you might expect. So, when you type `r1` or `r2` (i.e: `ModuleA/RunnerR1:run` or `ModuleA/RunnerR2:run`), SBT will employ the delegaton algorithm in order to find tasks and settings which, depending on how these tasks and settings were defined, it will end up running tasks from scopes you do not expect, or finding settings from scopes you do not expect.

```scala
lazy val ModuleA =
  project
    .in(file("ModuleA"))
    .settings(buildSettings:_*)
    .configs(RunnerR1,RunnerR2)
    .settings(inConfig(RunnerR1)(
      forkRunOptions ++
        Seq(
          mainClass in Compile :=  Option("sbt.tests.issueX.Application1"))):_*)
```

This issue is related to usability, since the API provided by SBT is misleading. Eventually this pattern can be improved or better documented, but it's more a usability problem than anything else.

### Circumventing the difficulty

Please find below how this issue can be circumvented.

Since `ForkOptions` is private, we have to provide our own way of running applications, which is based on SBT code, as much as possible.

In a nutshell, we have to guarantee that we redefine `run`, `runMain` and `runner` in all configurations we have.

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._


//-------------------------------------------------------------
// This file contains a solution for the problem presented by
// https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2247
//-------------------------------------------------------------


lazy val buildSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ runSettings

lazy val runSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] =
  Seq(
    fork in (Compile, run) := true)


def forkRunOptions(s: Scope): Seq[Setting[_]] =
  Seq(
    // see: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2247
    // see: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2244
    runner in run in s := {
      val forkOptions: ForkOptions =
        ForkOptions(
          workingDirectory = Some((baseDirectory in ThisBuild).value),
          bootJars         = Nil,
          javaHome         = (javaHome       in s).value,
          connectInput     = (connectInput   in s).value,
          outputStrategy   = (outputStrategy in s).value,
          runJVMOptions    = (javaOptions    in s).value,
          envVars          = (envVars        in s).value)
      new {
        val fork_ = (fork in run).value
        val config: ForkOptions = forkOptions
      } with ScalaRun {
        override def run(mainClass: String, classpath: Seq[File], options: Seq[String], log: Logger): Option[String] =
          javaRunner(
            Option(mainClass), Option(classpath), options,
            Some("java"), Option(log), fork_,
            config.runJVMOptions, config.javaHome, config.workingDirectory, config.envVars, config.connectInput, config.outputStrategy)
      }
    },
    runner  in runMain in (s) := (runner in run in (s)).value,
    run     in (s) <<= Defaults.runTask    (fullClasspath in s, mainClass in run in s, runner in run in s),
    runMain in (s) <<= Defaults.runMainTask(fullClasspath in s,                        runner in runMain in s)
  )


def javaRunner(mainClass: Option[String] = None,
               classpath: Option[Seq[File]] = None,
               options: Seq[String],
               javaTool: Option[String] = None,
               log: Option[Logger] = None,
               fork: Boolean = false,
               jvmOptions: Seq[String] = Nil,
               javaHome: Option[File] = None,
               cwd: Option[File] = None,
               envVars: Map[String, String] = Map.empty,
               connectInput: Boolean = false,
               outputStrategy: Option[OutputStrategy] = Some(StdoutOutput)): Option[String] = {

  def runner(app: String,
             args: Seq[String],
             cwd: Option[File] = None,
             env: Map[String, String] = Map.empty): Int = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

    val cmd: Seq[String] = app +: args
    val pb = new java.lang.ProcessBuilder(cmd.asJava)
    if (cwd.isDefined) pb.directory(cwd.get)
    pb.inheritIO
    //FIXME: set environment
    val process = pb.start()
    if (fork) 0
    else {
      def cancel() = {
        if(log.isDefined) log.get.warn("Background process cancelled.")
        process.destroy()
        15
      }
      try process.waitFor catch {
        case e: InterruptedException => cancel()
      }
    }
  }

  val app: String = javaHome.fold("") { p => p.absolutePath + "/bin/" } + javaTool.getOrElse("java")
  val jvm: Seq[String] = jvmOptions.map(p => p.toString)
  val cp: Seq[String] =
    classpath
      .fold(Seq.empty[String]) { paths =>
        Seq(
          "-cp",
          paths
            .map(p => p.absolutePath)
            .mkString(java.io.File.pathSeparator))
      }
  val klass = mainClass.fold(Seq.empty[String]) { name => Seq(name) }
  val xargs: Seq[String] = jvm ++ cp ++ klass ++ options

  if(log.isDefined)
    if(fork) {
      log.get.info(s"Forking: ${app} " + xargs.mkString(" "))
    } else {
      log.get.info(s"Running: ${app} " + xargs.mkString(" "))
    }

  if (cwd.isDefined) IO.createDirectory(cwd.get)
  val exitCode = runner(app, xargs, cwd, envVars)
  if (exitCode == 0)
    None
  else
    Some("Nonzero exit code returned from " + app + ": " + exitCode)
}


addCommandAlias("r1",       "ModuleA/RunnerR1:run")
addCommandAlias("r2",       "ModuleA/RunnerR2:run")


lazy val RunnerR1 = sbt.config("RunnerR1").extend(Compile)
lazy val RunnerR2 = sbt.config("RunnerR2").extend(Compile)


lazy val root =
  project
    .in(file("."))
    .settings(buildSettings:_*)
    .aggregate(ModuleA)

lazy val ModuleA =
  project
    .in(file("ModuleA"))
    .settings(buildSettings:_*)
    .configs(RunnerR1,RunnerR2)
    .settings(inConfig(RunnerR1)(
      forkRunOptions(ThisScope) ++
        Seq(
          mainClass :=  Option("sbt.tests.issueX.Application1"))):_*)
    .settings(inConfig(RunnerR2)(
      forkRunOptions(ThisScope) ++
        Seq(
          mainClass :=  Option("sbt.tests.issueX.Application2"))):_*)
```