# Overriding integration test configuration in sbt plugin masks run task

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

Consider the following sbt plugin definition which "overrides" the default "it" configuration to extend the Test configuration (for reasons discussed at [How to make "test" classes available in the "it" (integration test) configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624574/how-to-make-test-classes-available-in-the-it-integration-test-configuratio))

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  private lazy val IntegrationTest = config("it") extend(Test)

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    ...
  ) ++ inConfig(IntegrationTest)(Defaults.itSettings)

  override def projectConfigurations: Seq[Configuration] = IntegrationTest :: Nil
}
```

While this seems to work in general, it "masks" the run task. See the following sbt output from a project which uses the above described plugin:

```
[myproject] $ inspect run
[info] Input task: Unit
[info] Description:
[info]  Runs a main class, passing along arguments provided on the command 
line.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file://myproject/}myproject/it:run
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:307
...
```

Note **it:run** instead of **compile:run**. Somehow the re-definition of the "it" config seems to re-define/mask the *run* task. This does not happen if I choose e.g. "fun" instead of "it". I'm using sbt 0.13.15.

Any idea what's going on here and how to prevent the *run* task from being masked?

Comment: Could this be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243981/how-can-i-override-tasks-run-and-runmain-in-sbt-to-use-my-own-forkopti/33244341#33244341?

Comment: They same actually happens if I simply do `override def projectConfigurations: Seq[Configuration] = Seq(Configurations.IntegrationTest extend (Test))` instead of redefining my own `lazy val IntegrationTest`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a missing plugin dependency on `sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin` which provides the mechanisms to compile/test/run/package Java/Scala projects (see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Using-Plugins.html).

Adding

```
override def requires: Plugins = plugins.JvmPlugin
```

seems to resolve the problem.